# MySQL Insert Failing with Duplicate Entry on Index

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, sql-insert, innodb

I am trying to do an insert statement. I have an unique index setup that combines phone_number and niche.

> INSERT INTO CV_YP.table (phone_number,website,niche) VALUES
> (1231231234, 'website.com', 'fitness')

The return value says I have a duplicate entry but the phone number is different then the one I just tried to insert.

> ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 1: Duplicate entry '2147483647-fitness' for
> key 'idx_table_phone_number_niche'

I can't figure out why MySQL thinks my insert is related to the index duplication it returns.

Comment: Use a `VARCHAR`, not `INT` for phone numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think if you run this query

```sql
SELECT * FROM CV_YP.table WHERE phone_number = '2147483647' AND niche = 'fitness';
```

you will find more than 1 row, so I think its a violation of the unique index, so when the engine tries to check for uniqueness on the new data this error fire

### update

I think your phone number isn't `1231231234` right?
and it's a number greater than `2147483647` and you use phone_number data type as int

If that true I think you need to change the data type of the `phone_number` column because the max value of int is `2147483647` so when you insert the new number the engine sees it as the max value which is `2147483647` and try to insert it.

Comment: I ran it and it only returns a single row. The row looks normal.